Integrating Google Authentication with NextAuth in a Next.js App
I have this auth.js file for configuration:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const {
    handlers : { GET, POST },
} = NextAuth({
   providers: [
       GoogleProvider({
           clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
           clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
           authorization: {
               params: {
                   prompt: "consent",
                   access_type: "offline",
                   response_type: "code"
               }
           }
       })
   ]
});


I'm exporting it from src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js file like that:
export { GET, POST } from '../../../../auth.js';


but when I'm trying to go to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin I have this error:

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^15.0.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.10",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}



Solved by changing next-auth version on beta like that:
npm i next-auth@beta

